# Converting mysql_* to mysqli_* issue

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using `MySQLConverterTool` to convert my web application,

first issue i faced is code getting to big i dont even understand what that means? It was very small code before and now i see this is too big.

```
//old code
$ask_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ask_id']);

//after convert
$ask_id = ((isset($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) && is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $_POST['ask_id']) : ((trigger_error("[MySQLConverterToo] Fix the mysql_escape_string() call! This code does not work.", E_USER_ERROR)) ? "" : ""));
```

Its working fine but i want to know if its correct way of `mysqli_*` or is there some issue or bug i need to fix in line?

I also want to know how i can make this part secure

```
if (isset($_POST['asking-money'])) {
    $dailyBonus = 10000;
    $update = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "UPDATE users SET ask_time='$newtime', bonus='dailyBonus'  WHERE id='$userid'");
// some more calculation
}
```

Comment: You can forget about security if using "MySQLConverterTool". There are no free cookies, you know.

Comment: If you have the time, you should try to re-write your queries using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Yes i have run it on full web folder. and did backup. @YourCommonSense

Comment: There is no use for hasty rewrite. You can keep your code with old mysql all right. If you aren't going to refactor your code - just keep it as is. If you are - refactor it sensibly, not mechanically. Take yourself a database abstraction layer and make it used for all the database interactions. mysqli is NOT such a layer, but API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first bit of code looks like it (grossly) added a giant ternary statement to check that the variables you were using were at least set, but other than that you should just be able to use:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $_POST['ask_id'])
```

As for security with the SQL query, try using Prepared Statements instead of directly querying with variables

[mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Thank you @rogue for making it short.

Comment: No problem!, but you might want to look into not using third-party tools to convert your code. Learning it yourself will help you understand it a little more closely. As @LabibIsmaiel mentioned, much of the mysql_* functions just added an "i" after the function name.

Answer (score 2):

for the mysqli_* part, most of the things that used to be done with mysql_* remained almost the same with a new prefix, so, most likely there is no problem
and for the how to make it secure, just evaluate and prepare all the parameters being passed from the user before using them in the query, in other words, NEVER under any case, use the user input directly in a query. other than that the code seems very fine to me.

Comment: Thank you @labib for making it clear and understandable for me. My website got hacked today so trying to solve all the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

The first code is a **ternary statement** (short way for if/else). Way too much, my opinion.

I recommend [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and it's [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), if you're able to use it. It's very secure and easy to handle.

By the way: try to avoid the `MySQLConverterTool`. It's hard to get into this code after months. **K** eep **i** t **s** mart and **s** imple! :-)

Good luck!